# Cordova plugin for sending automated email(without user interaction)

Tags: cordova

I am working on an cordova based app and need to send emails from the app without the user interaction when the user presses a button.
I found many plugins which allow user to compose an email using the native email app(gmail,mail etc). I didn't find any plugins which support sending emails without user interaction.
Please let me know if there is any such plugin which is available for cordova based app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use either cordova-smtp-client or cordova-plugin-smtp-client (which is based on the former).  The downside is that those appear to require SMTP server and login information, as opposed to using the built-in email app to send without user interaction.